# Can I set a the Keystore property using a URL path?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, jax-ws, pki

I'm attempting to get 2-way SSL authentication working for a JAX-WS web service client on Google App Engine.

I'm relatively sure I can set the client's private key by casting to a BindingProvider and setting the `javax.net.ssl.keystore` property, like so:

```
WebServicePortType service = new WebService().getWebServicePort();
((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "client_cert.p12"
```

All the examples I can find presume `client_cert.p12` to be a file on the local filesystem.

Since we're on Google App Engine, we're prohibited from accessing the file system directly.

Will this context accept a URL for the keystore location?  If not, is there any way I can set the keystore on the web service that doesn't require file system access?

Thanks

**Edit:**

`SSLSocketFactory`, `SSLContext`, `KeyManager`, and `KeyManagerFactory` all aren't allowed on GAE.

Comment: Is is possible to create a file in GAE ?

Comment: This documentation makes it sound like I may be able to: https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#readfile, but I'm still unsure of how to set the javax.net.ssl.keystore property.  All the examples I find specify a String file name as the value being assigned.

Answer (score 2):

I Googled and got following workaround from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/372437/java/java/javax-net-ssl-keyStore-system).

1. read the keystore file as a resource stream :MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jarCertFile);
2. write it to local file
3. set keystore property to local file, System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",trustStore);

But it needs that you should be able to create a local file in GAE which seems possible after reading the link you mentioned. You can configure this code in a `ServletContextListener` which would create this file on application start up.

EDIT:

This work around assumes that the keystore file is bundled in your application archive.

Comment: Just found out we no longer have to do this, so I can't test if it worked (no server to hit) but I'll +1 since it looks like it should do the trick.  I'll revisit the answer soon if anyone else requires this of us.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, this approach won't work on GAE, since you are NOT allowed to write to files. Probably the documentation changed since this answer was posted.